# How to select different users filtering of certain results?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query:

```
select * 
  from traffic 
 group 
    by type
     , date
     , address 
having count(date and type and address) > 3 
   and status = 0
```

I want to select all details of distinct users entering the same type, date, address having count(date and type and address)>3 and status=0.

Here is the table

```
 traffic

slno | username | lat | longi | message | dat | time | type | address | status
```

The above query works, but my query shows results if the same user enters the same data more than three times. I want to see results when *different* users enter the same traffic data.

```
+==========+
| traffic  |
+==========+
| slno     | 
| username | 
| lat      | 
| longi    | 
| message  | 
| dat      | 
| time     | 
| type     | 
| address  | 
| status   |
+----------+
```

Comment: It is really hard to read your question. Edit it and don't forget to add your query been you tried. Where is first table and second table?

Comment: "select *
from traffic 
group by type,date,address 
having count(date and type and address)>3 
and status=0."

Comment: Where is your first table and second table? Edit your question, not add in comments and don't forget the result.

Comment: Above one is the query.The query shows if same users entered same data more than 3 times .I want to get if same data should be entered by more than different 3 different users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select traffic records where more than 3 distinct users have the same traffic data :

```
SELECT *
FROM `traffic`
WHERE `status` = 0
GROUP BY `type`, `date`, `address`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `username`) > 3
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd25d2/1)

If you want to select the corresponding users :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM `traffic` t 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT `username`)
  FROM `traffic`
  WHERE `status` = 0
  GROUP BY `type`, `date`, `address`
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `username`) > 3
) x
ON t.`type` = x.`type`
AND t.`date` = x.`date`
AND t.`address` = x.`address`
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85000/4)

Comment: thanku..but i didn't want to show if same user entered the same traffic data morethan 3 times

Comment: So what do you want ? More that 3 different users having the same data ?

Comment: ya....i didn't want if same user entered same data more than 3 times.The same data will be entered by different users

Comment: Thanku very much..and pls tell what is this t.type and x.type.the variable 't 'and 'x' means what??

Comment: t and x are aliases I deliberately chose. It is use to make the query shorter by avoiding repeating the entire name each time.

Comment: it also selects users having status 1.

Comment: Add a where close at the end

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean like this :

```
select username, date, type, address
from traffic 
where status = 0
group by username, date, type, address
having count(date) > 3 
and count(type) > 3 
and count(address) > 3
```

Comment: You just adding some additional info, I updated my answer again. Cheers~

Comment: This query works.but if same user entered same information more than 3 times,it will show.But i want to get different users entered same result

Comment: I don't understand. Can you post the result from this query and show us what your desired result in your question?